# SQLite: Archiving records in different database or table

Tags: performance, archive

My architectural performance problem is a legacy problem: multi-user access on a SQLite database in shared network folder. (Yes, I know, but I cannot change this!)

I'd like to archive records of some (not all) tables which are older than a specified date. This is to improve performance, since I realized that the program is much faster with 200 records instead of 20.000 (of the past 10 years).

There are two approaches:

1. Duplicate the database (structure) and move records from one database to another, after that shrinking the working database with VACUUM. (Current value of one special database: 111 K productive + 7.330 K archive)
2. Create archive tables within productive database and move records from one table to the other, after that shrinking the working database with VACUUM.

Approach 2 will be much easier to keep control of (e. g. one transaction can be used for transferring/archiving data), but it will keep everything in one database. Most of the time, I will only access the small working table. Only in quite rare cases there will be a search for old records in the big archive table.

What performance behavior do I have to expect? What will be faster/better?

Kind regards,
Mate

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the following behavior, relevant table with 250 records:

1. Two databases, production database 150 K
2. One Database incl. archive-table, shrinked 4700 K

I tested database on local drive and on network shared drive, on network share with three concurrent processes running on my PC, with 100 reading operations of each process and a random sleep time between accesses of 50 to 150 ms to avoid massiv parallel operation.

Result:

1. Two databases: 1128 ms
2. One database:  1186 ms (+5 %)

I come to the conclusion, that **in this scenario** performance gain is hardly measurable, so I will **archive to a different table of the same database**. The big advantage of this solution is that I have full control of archiving procedure **since I can use a transaction**. On two databases, I cannot have a single transaction, and therefore I need to backup and restore database files manually, which might go wrong because of some strange reasons as well. It will be really hard to produce a consistent result in this case.